# Prolog: what does a 's' before a variable name stand for?

Tags: prolog, operators

I'm coding a Mastermind solver in Prolog (I'm using SWI-Prolog) as part of a university requirement. I never programmed in Prolog before so excuse me if I might not use the correct terms.

I'm having problems incrementing my black and whites counters (representing how many colors are in the correct positions and how many are in the code but misplaced).

I found this example online (full code [here](http://www.cs.unipr.it/China/Benchmarks/Prolog/mastermind.pl)):

```
determine_blacks([],[],[],[],0).
determine_blacks([Color|Try],[Color|Code],ReducedTry,ReducedCode,s Black) :-
    determine_blacks(Try,Code,ReducedTry,ReducedCode,Black).
determine_blacks([Color1|Try],[Color2|Code],
         [Color1|ReducedTry],[Color2|ReducedCode],Black) :-
    color(_,Color1), color(_,Color2),
    \+(Color1 == Color2),
    determine_blacks(Try,Code,ReducedTry,ReducedCode,Black).
```

I was wondering: what does the **'s' in "s Black" (line2)** stand for? I noticed that if I remove it, the counter will stop incrementing. So I guess this somehow does the trick, but I couldn't find it in the documentation.

I'd also appreciate if you could explain what the **'\+' (line7)** is supposed to do. This code is a bit too advanced for my level and I'm struggling with it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By itself `s` (or any other functor, for that matter) do not have any intrinsic meaning.

It gets meaning by the way it is utilized in the Prolog code (and queries).

---

Telling from the [`MASTERMIND.PL`](http://www.cs.unipr.it/China/Benchmarks/Prolog/mastermind.pl) source code that your question links to, the unary prefix operator `s/1` gets utilized in
`extend_code/1` (line #110), `finished/1` (line #173), `determine_blacks/5` (line #231), and  `determine_whites/5` (line #247).

`s/1` is defined as a unary prefix operator<sup>1</sup> in line #54:

```
:- op(150, fy, s).
```

All this does is allow us writing `s s s 0` instead of `s(s(s(0)))`.

In my opinion, this provides no benefit *whatsoever*.

---

<sup>**Footnote 1:** For more information on Prolog operators, read [this part of the SICStus Prolog manual](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dsyn_002dops.html).</sup>

Comment: oh, thank you! I had no idea what that line meant :D

Comment: @PLB. I added a link to the relevant section of the SICStus Prolog manual... Enjoy!

Comment: Oh great, I thought that it must be something like this. BTW, for a beginner, I think it's better to stick on the `s(s(s(0)))` notation. Operators are advanced concepts. Prolog is hard enough to learn in the beginning (especially for people who are used to procedural/declarative programming languages like Java and C#)

Comment: Thank you for the link! #one more thing: what does '\+' do?

Comment: @PLB. `\+ G` means that the goal `G` is not provable. For more information, read https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dsem.html , and in particular: https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dsem_002dctr.html .

Comment: @SQLOTL. Adding operators without a good reason (and I mean a really good reason) is begging for trouble. It can be done, but in most cases better don't do it...

Answer (score 2):

That looks like it this is a snippet out of a bigger program. The `s` here is typically used for building up or for reducing a list in recursion.

You can see the `s` a kind of wildcard. The idea of this statement is to find all lines which have a `Black`at the end and attach to an existing list.

Comment: yes it is a snippet. I added a link to the full code. Frankly I don't understand *where* the lines are summed...